# Tmux 1.8 gives "failed to connect to server" when trying to source a file

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have `tmux 1.8` on my machine, and it works correctly if I just invoke it on the command line with `tmux` on the command line.

However, when I try to run `tmux source-file <any-file>`, I always get the error message `failed to connect to server` and `tmux` fails to start.

I started by trying to source the file [here](http://www.hackzine.org/auto-starting-tmux-with-panes-services.html), but during the course of debugging I was able to reproduce the problem with a completely empty file.

Here is my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a

bind h   select-pane -L
bind j   select-pane -D
bind k  select-pane -U
bind l  select-pane -R

bind -t vi-copy Enter begin-selection
```

Is there something in particular I need to do to make `tmux 1.8` source files correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear what the error was, but I did find an effective workaround.

Assuming my `<any-file>` above has the following lines:

```
Command1
Command2
Command3
```

My workaround is to just write a script with:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux Command1
tmux Command2
tmux Command3
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you did not have a server running. Only certain commands will automatically start a server (`new-session`, `attach-session`, and `start-server`); `source-file` is not one of these commands.

You can include a `start-server` command in the same `tmux` command to explicitly start a server:

```
tmux start-server \; source some-file
```

Note: The *tmux* server will automatically exit when it has no sessions, so unless you create a session (either in your `~/.tmux.conf`, or `some-file`, or via another `new-session` command included in the `tmux` command), then the server will exit just after the above `tmux` command finished.

---

Alternatively, prior to running your `tmux source …` command, you could just start a placeholder session that exists just to keep the server running:

```
tmux new-session -ds placeholder 2>/dev/null
⋮
tmux source some-file
```